# Why can't `std::min` be used between `int` and `long long int`

Tags: c++, types, max, min

So I just want to know that why I can't pass values with different datatypes in min and max function?

```
int a=7;
long long int b=5;
long long int c=min(a,b);
cout<<c;
```

My doubt arises because what I know for sure that compiler can implicitly type cast from smaller datatype(int) to larger datatype(long long int) so why not compiler couldn't type cast here!

Comment: Please always use a tag for the programming language in question.  I suppose this is C++?

Comment: yeah. My apology.

Comment: they are templates, that's why. Deduction doesn't work because two deduced variants are ambiguous. use explicit cast.

Comment: I know that both variants are different but isn't that responsibility of a compiler to do implicit type cast if possible?

Comment: Got it. It's a template class. template <class T> const T& min (const T& a, const T& b); So if T is int then both parameters are int.

Comment: @kinjal to what? both variants have equal right to exist. There is no defined rule which is converted to which.

Comment: @kinjal -- What is the data type that would be returned from `std::min` if both types are different?  Is it `int`?  `long long`?  Something in-between?  What rule would the template have to follow as to the return type if both parameters are differing types?  See the rabbit hole we get into?

Comment: It's not a class, it's a function. `class` doesn't mean a class here, it simply means that `T` is a type template parameter.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie No. At first I thought that compiler will do the implicit type conversion from int to long long int because it's compiler responsibility. But, I am wrong.

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie Got it. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

This comes down to how `std::min` and `std::max` were designed.

They could've had two different types for the two parameters, and use something like [`std::common_type`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/common_type) to figure out a good result type. But instead they have the same type for both parameters, so the two arguments you pass must also have the same type.

> compiler can implicitly type cast from smaller datatype(int) to larger datatype(long long int)

Yeah, but it also can implicitly convert back from `long long` to `int`. ("Cast" isn't the right word, it means an *explicit* conversion.)

The rule is that when a function parameter participates in template argument deduction, no implicit conversions are allowed for the argument passed to that parameter. Deduction rules are already compilcated, allowing some implicit conversions (i.e. to wider arithmetic types) would make them even more complex.

Comment: I have learnt two reasons why: 1. it's a template. template <class T> const T& min (const T& a, const T& b); 2. no implicit conversions are allowed. thanks.

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie 1. I think that if both parameters has different datatypes then function overloading is not possible as we can see that both variables has same template. 2. then did you mean that when a function parameter participates in template argument deduction, no implicit conversions are allowed for the argument passed to that parameter is a wrong statement?

Answer (score -3):

Because there is loss of precision error comes when you do this they are made for the `int` datatypes so you cannot pass `long` or something like `float`.
You have to implicit cast them.

Comment: `std::min` is a function template, it is not "made for the `int`"

Comment: not it. precision does have anything with parameter deduction or implicit casts